# looping over multiple aws profiles with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-iam, boto3

I cant seem to find a really good way to initiate multiple sessions with boto3. If I have 10 accounts and want to lets say, make a new IAM user, I cant seem to change the boto3.session.Session with new calls.

So example code:

```
    for user in usernames:
       for acct in accounts:
           boto3.session.Session(profile_name=acct)
           print 'trying account: %s' % acct
           try:
               uname = IAM.create_user(UserName=user)
               uname
               print uname
               print row_template % header
               print row_template % tuple(['-' * len(h) for h in header])
               print row_template % (user, acct)
           except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
               print e
```

However, it will only create a session for the default session and will not change it. I cant seem to find a way to close the session either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You are not using the session your boto3.session() returns. Instead you are using the same default session. You can develop from the following code snippet:

```
   for acct in accounts:
       session = boto3.Session(profile_name=acct)
       iam = session.client('iam')
       for user in usernames:
           iam.create_user(UserName=user)
```

Comment: Hi what is 'accounts'? how is that calculated?